# /usr/bin/perl : Symbol look-up error; undefined symbol: Perl_Istack_sp_ptr

Tags: perl, lookup, symbols, lcov

Whenever I am using `lcov` command (lcov-1.9) for `gcc 3.4` compiled objects and the corresponding `.gcda` files, I get an error.

Command I execute:

```
lcov -c -d . --gcov-tool /usr/bin/gcov34  -o datafile
```

Error:

```
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /u01/R122_EBS/fs1/FMW_Home/webtier/perl/lib/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Cwd/Cwd.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Istack_sp_ptr
```

Is it because something is wrong with Perl? (But, Perl on our development server should be probably be alright.) Or because of some version mismatches between lcov and GCC or something else?

Any clues?

Comment: Generally speaking, that error would indicate a Perl extension (XS module) compiled using one Perl is being used by a different, incompatible build. Not sure where Perl even comes in to your problem, though.

Comment: lcov is a perl script. That's why Perl comes to the problem. But yes, the problem is that the Cwd module that is being used was compiled with another Perl version. Solution is to find the right path to the Perl that owns that XS extension, or to reinstall Cwd module.