# Symbol lookup error undefined symbol: mysql_init

Tags: linux, perl

When I am trying the below perl scrip, I am getting the "perl:symbol lookup error". It looks if I modify the PATH currently I could have resolve the issue. But I am not sure what lib I should bring to the PATH. Please let me know how do I resolve this and feel free to share if you have any different solutions or workarounds to this issue.

```
[root@localhost]# ./create_defs.pl --user root --password amma --db=d1 --table=tbl1

**perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysql_init**

[root@localhost]# ll /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so

-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 333965 Sep 12 13:05 /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so

[root@localhost]# echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/root/bin
```

---

**From comment**

Here is the perl version in my server, so how do I resolve this issue?

```
[root@localhost lib]# perl -v

This is perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

---

**From comment**

Thank you for responding. Following are the commands I used to do the installation

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::DBI'
perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBD::mysql'
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::DBD::mysql'
perl -MCPAN -e 'DBI' perl -MCPAN -e 'DBD::mysql'
perl -MCPAN -e 'install perl-DBD-MySQL'
install Bundle::Mysql
```

Following are the commands I used, can you please guide me how to clear all the perl module and do the reinstallation.

Comment: There are possible errors.
First have `use strict;` in your script.
Second the mysql drive installation has an error.
probe `find / -name mysql.so`

Comment: @DenisKohl - OP's post shows that the `mysql.so` file does exist.  In [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226772/usr-bin-perl-symbol-look-up-error-undefined-symbol-perl-istack-sp-ptr) of this nature it was pointed out that this error is *usually* caused by the module being compiled for a different version of Perl than is currently running.

Comment: [root@localhost lib]# perl -v
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
Here is the perl version in my server, so how do I resolve this issue.

Comment: The DBD::MySQL perl module appears to be either installed incorrectly, or it doesn't match the version of mysql that's installed. What Linux distribution. How was DBD::MySQL installed?

Comment: I have done the DBD::mysql installation with help of cpan
cpan[1]> force install DBD::mysql   Result :Running make install
Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into architecture dependent library tree
Installing /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so
Appending installation info to /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/perllocal.pod
  CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.028.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK I have done the same again and still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a standard Perl error message but reflects a problem with your perl installation.

You have multiple different builds of perl that aren't playing nice.

Without being able to delve into your system the best advice I can give is to remove perl completely and reinstall.

Comment: Thank you for responding, following are the commands I used to do the installation .. perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::DBI'
  perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBD::mysql'
  perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::DBD::mysql'
  perl -MCPAN -e 'DBI'
  perl -MCPAN -e 'DBD::mysql'
  perl -MCPAN -e 'install perl-DBD-MySQL'
 install Bundle::Mysql
Following are the commands I used, can you please guide me how to clear all the perl module and do the reinstallation.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you any further. I have copied your comment to your original question. Please edit your question to correct my additions and if you want to add anything more.